# Woocommerce - Add delivery charge to cart total for products in certain category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the code below to add a delivery charge if the total cart contents is below 5.

However, I only want this to apply to products which aren't in the category  'accessories'. So for example, if the user has 4 products but 1 product from the 'accessory' category then it shouldn't include add the product from the  'accessory' cat.

I know i need to use an operator to test if any of the products are within the 'accessory' category and if so break the statement but I'm not sure how i would do this in Woocommerce.

Can anyone help me please?

```
/**
 * Add custom fee on article specifics
 * @param WC_Cart $cart
 */
function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
    $fees = 0;


        // Check if odds and if it's the right item
        if( $cart->cart_contents_count < 5){
            get_post_meta
            $fees += 48;
        }


    if( $fees != 0 ){
        $cart->add_fee( 'Delivery charge', $fees);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out if anyone gets stuck in the future

```
// Hook before adding fees 
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');
    function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ) {

    $fees = 0;
    $total_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
    $total = 0;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){ 
     $product = $item['data'];

        if( ! has_term( array( 19 ), 'product_cat', $product->id ) ){
            $total += $item['quantity'];
        } 

     }

      if($total < 5) { 
          $fees += 48;
      } 


    if( $fees != 0 ){
        // You can customize the descriptions here
        $cart->add_fee( 'Delivery charge', $fees);
    }
}
```